# Semicolon's relation with reverse proxy

Tags: web-application, appsec, java

What is the relation of semicolon with reverse proxy and how is it able to escape context/servlet mapping in reverse proxies such as IIS, NGINX, Apache?

Like I've seen multiple times where people have reported the use of semicolon to escape context/servlet mapping in reverse proxies.

```
For example- in a website 

    1. /health = 200 OK
    2. /admin/resource/ = 403 Forbidden
    3. /health/;admin/resource/ =  loads the path /admin/resource 200 OK
```

My question is why does this happen and what is the relation of semicolon with escaping the context/servlet mapping?

Comment: Is this an actually real example?

Comment: @ysdx Yessir! It is.

Comment: I learned the "empty path parameter" trick which is can be quite powerful.

Comment: Semicolons are off topic on this site :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java Servlet and [JAX-WS](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/ws/rs/MatrixParam.html) have support for so-called [Matrix Parameters](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html): each component path can have a series of parameters.

For example:

```
/foo;param1=a;param2=b/bar;param3=c;param4=d
```

In the [servlet specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf), these are referenced to as “path parameters”:

> Path parameters that are part of a GET request (as defined by HTTP 1.1) are not exposed by these APIs. They must be parsed from the String values returned by the getRequestURI method or the getPathInfo method.
>
> [...]
>
> The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the request object **minus** the context path and **the path parameters**.
>
> [...]
>
> The session ID must be encoded as a path parameter in the URL string. The name of the parameter must be jsessionid. Here is an example of a URL containing encoded path information:
>
> http://www.example.com/catalog/index.html;jsessionid=1234

This usage is somewhat documented in the URI RFC3986:

> the semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are
> often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to
> that segment.  [...] For example, one URI producer might use a segment
> such as "name;v=1.1" to indicate a reference to version 1.1 of
> "name",

### SpringWeb

Let's try this basic Spring (Boot, Web) applications:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @PostMapping("/api/reboot")
    String newEmployee() {
        // TODO, do the actual reboot
        return "Rebooting";
    }
}
```

We can trigger the `reboot()` endpoint by either:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/reboot' 
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/reboot;whatever' 
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;whatever/reboot'
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/;whateher/reboot'
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/;/api/;/reboot'
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/;/api/reboot'
```

Now imagine that we have protected this `/reboot` endpoint in our reverse proxy. For example with nginx:

```
location /api/ {
    auth_basic “Protected”;
    #...
}
```

This protects any resource starting the the "/api/" string using some basic authentication.

However when using 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;whatever/reboot':

- nginx does not apply the protection;
- the Java Servlet interprets `;whatever` as matrix parameters of the `/api/reboot` path and triggers the `reboot()` endpoint.

This way we can bypass the protection implemented in the reverse proxy.

In this example, we exploited a discrepancy between how the Java applications and the reverse proxy interprets URI to bypass a protection in the reverse proxy.

In the same way a buggy Java authentication middleware (`ServletFilter`) could possibly be bypassed using such approach.

### Servlet API

Let's look at how, Matrix parameter work with Servlet:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/api/foo")
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {  
 
    @Override
    protected void doPost(
      HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("contextPath=" + request.getContextPath() + '\n');
        out.print("requestURI=" + request.getRequestURI() + '\n');
        out.print("servletPath=" + request.getServletPath() + '\n');
        out.print("pathInfo=" + request.getPathInfo() + '\n');
    }

}
```

Let's test this servlet:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/foo'
contextPath=
requestURI=/api/foo
servletPath=/api/foo
pathInfo=null

$ curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;whatever/foo'
contextPath=
requestURI=/api;whatever/foo
servletPath=/api/foo
pathInfo=null

$ curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/foo;whatever'
contextPath=
requestURI=/api/foo;whatever
servletPath=/api/foo
pathInfo=null

$ curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/;/foo'
contextPath=
requestURI=/api/;/foo
servletPath=/api/foo
pathInfo=null

$ curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/;/api/foo'
contextPath=
requestURI=/;/api/foo
servletPath=/api/foo
pathInfo=nul
```

A `ServletFilter` enforcing some authorization/authentication based `.getRequestURI()` could for example be bypassed using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with IIS, nginx or Apache http server.

While there is a fundamental lack of references in your question you might  mean things like described in [How I Chained 4 Bugs(Features?) into RCE on Amazon Collaboration System](https://blog.orange.tw/2018/08/how-i-chained-4-bugs-features-into-rce-on-amazon.html). Bugs in these cases allowed an ACL bypass with specifically constructed path, where the normalized path was very different from the original path. Only ACL check was done on the original path (and allowed access) while action was done on the normalized path (which would have been blocked by the ACL).

None of this was broken logic was in any of the mentioned reverse proxies though, it was in the web application itself. And it is also not specific to a semicolon. It is a problem similar to [Time-of-check to time-of-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use), i.e. the thing which is checked for a security decision is not the same which is used later for the action.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply. Secondly, does this mean that semicolon has no relation with escaping context/servlet mapping and that this particular issue is with the web app itself?

Comment: @James: Use of semicolon in a special way is common with Java J2EE applications, see [Beware the HTTP Path Parameter in Java](https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/beware-the-http-path-parameter-in-java/). But again, this is a problem of the web application and not of the reverse proxy in front of it. You've asked about the reverse proxy. The mapping of path to servlet is usually done in the web application itself.